# Align key-value pair in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to set *Align key-value pair* in Pycharm Code Style? I'm looking for something that will reformat:

```
nickname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=24)
biography = models.TextField(default=BIO_DEFAULT_STRING)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='members/avatars/')
```

to:

```
nickname  = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=24)
biography = models.TextField(default=BIO_DEFAULT_STRING)
avatar    = models.ImageField(upload_to='members/avatars/')
```

I got it working in PhpStorm, can't find it in PyCharm.

Comment: Given that it violates the style guide, I'd be surprised if it was built into PyCharm.

Comment: That said, the documentation says you can copy code styles between languages - see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-code-style.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe: why would it violate the style guide?

Comment: ...because the style guide says not to do it? [*"Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations: ... More than one space around an assignment (or other) operator to align it with another."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves)

Comment: NB. "the style guide" in these comments is PEP8, which is for creating the standard library. For your own code, you're free to use Hungarian notation if it suits your team.

Comment: That violets the style guide? Who decided on that? It's hideous to have everything centered so close, hard to quickly distinct value and variable.

Answer (score 10):

You need a function from plugin [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162):

### `Menu` → `Code` → `Align to Columns`

---

#### Configure hot-keys

- `Settings` → `Keymap`
- Search *"Align to Columns"* and select
- `Add Keyboard Shortcut`(<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Set your shortcuts (my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
- Press `Apply` and `Ok`

Answer (score 7):

It is really strange, but PyCharm 2016 has this stuff, and i was to search the way to turn it OFF.
I found this question, while searching "How to turn align by value".

## File - Settings - Editor - Code Style - Python

There you need **Other** tab, where you'll find  **Dict Aligment** settings.
There is 3 types:

- Do not align
- Align on value
- Align on colon

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjual.png)

Have no idea why they added that stuff, maybe because of platform unification, but it is exist and was turned to `'Align on value'` by default for me after i've updeted PyCharm to 2016.2.

## UPDATE:

A litle bit more explanations:

It was asked how to make aligns in PyCharm code formating, for example in dicts.:

Here how does dict should looks like via PEP:

```
i_am_a_dict = {
    key:value,
    another_key:another_value,
    a_very_long_key:one_more_value
}
```

That's how does it looks for me in PyCharm after platform update (and such format DO NOT match PEP, but it can be done by PyCharm settings:

```
 i_am_a_dict = {
        key:            value,
        another_key:    another_value,
        a_very_long_key:one_more_value
    }
```

It was aligned by values. And the question was about "How to align key:values in PyCharm"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?